# Html link adding last page's id automatically

Tags: html

I m using wordpress menu to link pages and their sections like this. when i visit the link which contains id like "about-us#about-ceo" and after that if i click on a link "sixsigmaconsult.com/careers/" it automatically adds last visited page id like "sixsigmaconsult.com/careers/#about-ceo" what is the mistake?

```html
<ul>
<li><a href="http://sixsigmaconsult.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="https://sixsigmaconsult.com/about-us/">WHO WE ARE</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://sixsigmaconsult.com/about-us#about-ceo">About CEO</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sixsigmaconsult.com/about-us#about-ssc">About SSC</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="https://sixsigmaconsult.com/what-we-do/">What We Do</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://sixsigmaconsult.com/what-we-do#urban-development">Urban Development</a></li>
<li><a href="http://sixsigmaconsult.com/what-we-do#transportation">Transportation</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="https://sixsigmaconsult.com/careers/">Careers</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It can be a problem of wordpress or your browser cache. You can test this again after deleting your browser cache memory.

Comment: I tested it on different PC and after clearing cache also

Comment: Oh. The code you added there is no problem. can you give me the wp site link.

Comment: @acoder Sir please visit that website u can see the issue

Comment: I don't understand. And don't addressing as Sir.

Comment: @acoder Sorry.  website http://sixsigmaconsult.com

Comment: hey it is working in my PC.

Comment: @acoder visit links like i mentioned. U will see the difference